# Make matrix from list

Tags: prolog

Good morning.
I need your help.
I want to make a list of list (matrix with size SQRT(N)*SQRT(N)) from a list with Size N

I am tried but It does not work for me :(

```
gen(L,T,Matrix)
```

which T is the size of Matrix
You are free to add more param if you want

for example

```
gen([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3,Matrix)
Matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if your list length isn't a perfect square?  This seems easy: the list is just a row- or column-major representation of the matrix.  What's the problem?

Comment: Why do you need `T`? Why is the list not derived from the `length/2` of the list.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you specifically stuck? And, how is the matrix you want related to the list you're given?

Comment: To be honnest I want to check if a list is a magic square or not. I first thought that how to construct a matrix from this list, and then check the row sum and col sum.

Comment: For a list to be a magic square, the list must already be a matrix, correct? So it would already be a list of lists. So it's not clear now what you have given.

Comment: except that the list is a list of integer not a list of list

Comment: I update my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a fairly straightforward problem. The trick is to remember that `append/3` has many instantiation patterns, and can be used not just to glue lists together but also to *break them apart*:

```
?- append(X, Y, [1,2,3,4]).
X = [],
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = [1],
Y = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = [1, 2],
Y = [3, 4] ;
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [4] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4],
Y = [] ;
false.
```

You can use `length/2` to control the size of the list you make as well:

```
?- append(X, Y, [1,2,3,4]), length(X, 3).
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [4] ;
false.
```

This is almost everything you need right here. The rest is just wrapping this in a recursive call. You need a base case:

```
gen([], _, []).
```

This essentially says, my dimension doesn't matter if I'm out of flat-representation or matrix representation.

Now the recursive case:

```
gen(List, T, [Start|Rest]) :-
    append(Start, Remainder, List),
    length(Start, T),
    gen(Remainder, T, Rest).
```

This is a very basic recursive predicate. The `append/3` followed by `length/2` steps are the same as above; they establish a length `T` prefix of List as the next chunk of the result. Then we recursively apply ourselves to the remaining List to generate the Rest of the result.

As a cool side benefit, this predicate works both ways:

```
?- gen(X, 3, [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] ;
false.
```

How nice is that!