# Prolog - dividing list into n-elements sections

Tags: prolog

I have a predict which gets first N elements:

```
nfirst(N, _, Lnew) :- N =< 0, Lnew = [].
nfirst(_, [], []).
nfirst(N, [X|Y], [X|Y1]) :- N1 is N - 1, nfirst(N1, Y, Y1).
```

It works:
   % nfirst(3,[1,2,3,4,5,6],X).
   % X = [1, 2, 3]

I need a predict for divide list like below:

```
% divide([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],[3,2,1,2],X).
% X = [[a,b,c],[d,e],[f],[g,h]]
```

The best way is using nfirst.

Comment: What should `divide([a,b,c,d,e], [3, 4], X).` do? And do you have to use `nfirst/3` as you defined it? It is not the best way. A much better predicate to use than `nfirst/3` as you have it defined would be `nfirst(N, List, First, Rest)` where `First` is the first `N` elements and `R` is the rest.

Comment: Does this help? `split_at(N, List, [H|[T]]) :- append(H, T, List), length(H, N).`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very similar question to the one [I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44275707/812818). Again, the trick is to use `append/3` plus `length/2` to "bite off" a chunk of list, per my comment above:

```
split_at(N, List, [H|[T]]) :- append(H, T, List), length(H, N).
```

If you run that, you'll see this:

```
?- split_at(4, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], X).
X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]] ;
```

So this is the backbone of your program, and now you just need the usual recursive stuff around it. First, the base case, which says, if I'm out of list, I should be out of split locations, and thus out of result:

```
divide([], [], []).
```

Note that explicit base cases like this make your program more correct than something like `divide([], _, _)` because they will cause you to fail if you get too many split locations for your list size.

Now the recursive case is not difficult, but because `split_at/3` puts two things together in a list (probably a bad choice, you could make `split_at/4` as an improvement) you have to take them out, and it clouds the logic a bit here while making (IMO) a nicer API on its own.

```
divide(List, [Split|Splits], [Chunk|Rest]) :-
    split_at(Split, List, [Chunk, Remainder]),
    divide(Remainder, Splits, Rest).
```

This should be fairly straightforward: we're just taking a `Split` location, using it to chop up the `List`, and repeating the processing on what's left over. It seems to work as you expect:

```
?- divide([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],[3,2,1,2],X).
X = [[a, b, c], [d, e], [f], [g, h]] ;
false.
```

Hope this helps! Compare to the other answer, it may illuminate things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360424/prolog-remove-the-non-unique-elements

I need help again.