# Prolog - remove the non unique elements

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate to check if the element is member of list and looks the following:

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

When I called: ?- member(1,[2,3,1,4])
I get: true.

And now I have to use it to write predicate which will remove all non unique elements from list of lists like the following:

```
remove([[a,m,t,a],[k,a,w],[i,k,b,b],[z,m,m,c]],X).
X = [[t],[w],[i,b,b],[z,c]]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why `X = [[t],[k,w],[i,b,b],[z,c]]`? `k` occurs twice in `[[a,m,t,a],[k,a,w],[i,k,b,b],[z,m,m,c]]` and `b` occurs twice in the solution. This isn't making much sense.

Comment: sorry, its my mistake

Comment: @lurker: `b,b` is here because it occurs in only one sublist — presumably

Comment: @false, ok, but based upon the description and example, it's unclear to me definitively what the OP means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your example and @false's comment, the actual problem seems to be something like removing elements from each sublist that occur in any other sublist. My difficulty conceptualizing this into words has led me to build what I consider a pretty messy and gross piece of code.

So first I want a little helper predicate to sort of move `member/2` up to lists of sublists.

```
in_sublist(X, [Sublist|_])  :- member(X, Sublist).
in_sublist(X, [_|Sublists]) :- in_sublist(X, Sublists).
```

This is no great piece of work, and in truth I feel like it should be inlined somehow because I just can't see myself ever wanting to use this on its own.

Now, my initial solution wasn't correct and looked like this:

```
remove([Sub1|Subs], [Res1|Result]) :-
    findall(X, (member(X, Sub1), \+ in_sublist(X, Subs)), Res1),
    remove(Subs, Result).
remove([], []).
```

You can see the sort of theme I'm going for here though: let's use `findall/3` to enumerate the elements of the sublist in here and then we can filter out the ones that occur in the other lists. This doesn't quite do the trick, the output looks like this.

```
?- remove([[a,m,t,a],[k,a,w],[i,k,b,b],[z,m,m,c]], R).
R = [[t], [a, w], [i, k, b, b], [z, m, m, c]].
```

So, it starts off looking OK with `[t]` but then loses the plot with `[a,w]` because there is not visibility into the input `[a,m,t,a]` when we get to the first recursive call. There are several ways we could deal with it; a clever one would probably be to form a sort of zipper, where we have the preceding elements of the list and the succeeding ones together. Another approach would be to remove the elements in this list from all the succeeding lists before the recursive call. I went for a "simpler" solution which is messier and harder to read but took less time. I would strongly recommend you investigate the other options for readability.

```
remove(In, Out) :- remove(In, Out, []).
remove([Sub1|Subs], [Res1|Result], Seen) :-
    findall(X, (member(X, Sub1),
                \+ member(X, Seen),
                \+ in_sublist(X, Subs)), Res1),
    append(Sub1, Seen, Seen1),
    remove(Subs, Result, Seen1).
remove([], [], _).
```

So basically now I'm keeping a "seen" list. Right before the recursive call, I stitch together the stuff I've seen so far and the elements of this list. This is not particularly efficient, but it seems to get the job done:

```
?- remove([[a,m,t,a],[k,a,w],[i,k,b,b],[z,m,m,c]], R).
R = [[t], [w], [i, b, b], [z, c]].
```

This strikes me as a pretty nasty problem. I'm surprised how nasty it is, honestly. I'm hoping someone else can come along and find a better solution that reads better.

Another thing to investigate would be DCGs, which can be helpful for doing these kinds of list processing tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much, but what that means \+?

Comment: And the predicate findall is too advanced. Ihave to use only my predicates.

Comment: `\+` means negation.

Comment: "Type the Declaration of Independence backwards, in hand-cuffs, while tied to a chair, to prove you know it." No thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `library(reif)` for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl)|[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl):

```
lists_uniques(Xss, Yss) :-
   maplist(tfilter(in_unique_t(Xss)), Xss, Yss).

in_unique_t(Xss, E, T) :-
   tfilter(memberd_t(E), Xss, [_|Rs]),
   =(Rs, [], T).
```

Remark that while there is no restriction how to name a predicate, a non-relational, imperative name often hides the pure relation behind. `remove` is a real imperative, but we only want a relation. A relation between a list of lists and a list of lists with only unique elements.

An example usage:

```
?- lists_uniques([[X,b],[b]], [[X],[]]).
   dif(X, b).
```

So in this case we have left `X` an uninstantiated variable.  Therefore, Prolog computes the most general answer possible, figuring out what `X` has to look like.

(Note that the answer you have accepted incorrectly fails in this case)

Comment: There are certainly more efficient versions: In particular, there are much too many counts of the further elements.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use any libraries, because that is task from my university.

Comment: The copy the library into your solution!

Comment: @user: please see the added example!